# How can I remove compression artifacts around text?

Tags: batch-processing, compression

**Example**:

[image]

This seems to be a problem with using JPEG.  My questions are:

1. How to remove  the grey areas around the  text? What filter/process in GIMP/ImageMagick or other free image editing/scripting mediums would you recommend?
2. What would be a programmatic approach to cleaning an image like this? E.g. converting it to a bitmap and applying some filter or process using scripting, etc.
3. What is the preferred web friendly file format to not end up with
   such dirty looking images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All it really takes is a Levels, Curves, or Brightness adjustment. Almost any free or paid raster editing application has the capacity to raise the white point and lower the black point. This would, in turn, remove the grey, brighten the white, and darken the black.

Images don't customarily "end up" like that without some serious alteration somewhere such as saving a jpg as a jpg over and over again. (Don't do that with jpgs)

Comment: Or saving for web with a very very low quality. Really though because this is a text 'image' you'd be better served using a png. Jpegs are best for photographs. Or you could just type it instead of saving plain text as an image at all.