# Ways to remove/select scanning artifacts from document

Tags: gimp, batch-processing, script, image-processing, linux

I often receive scanned documents that has dots and grains in them. I often use the paintbrush in gimp to manually remove them, but it occurs to me that all the dots share so many similarities that a simple algorithm should be able to "white" them out automatically.

Take this example:
[image]

If blacks surrounded by whites in a given area is detected then select that said area for further processing:

[image]

Does anybody know of any scripting-way or plugin that can do such a thing?

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29901/gimp-how-to-remove-background-noise-artifacts-and-enhance-handwritten-text?rq=1 https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16624/how-can-i-remove-compression-artifacts-around-text?rq=1 https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/132865/need-to-improve-the-quality-of-images-with-gimp

Comment: G'MIC did the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a filter in the [G'MIC plugin](https://gmic.eu/) that could be used to get rid of the majority of the dots, although some larger ones may be left behind.  It's located under *Filters > G'MIC > Repair > Descpeckle*

Before and After

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. The "Repair Scanned Document" filter is just pure magic. I'll definitely support the G'MIC makers financially in the future for gifting their work of art.